# What is Difference between Sample division and floor division? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

'/' and '//'. what'S the use of those two operation and what is the difference.please help to explain.i was confused for using two operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//` is integer division.

```
>>> 6//4
1
>>> 6.0//4
1.0
```

The behavior of `/` varies between Python 2 and Python 3.
In general, `/` is regular floating point division, except for the case where two integers are divided in Python 2, in which case `/` falls back to the behavior of `//`.

Python 2:

```
>>> 6/4
1
>>> 6.0/4
1.5
```

Python 3:

```
>>> 6/4
1.5
>>> 6.0/4
1.5
```